# how to install two application with one installation?

Tags: android, installation, apk, single-responsibility-principle

i am new to android application.I have created two sample applications as Oneproject,Twoproject.when i run the Oneproject then the Twoproject automatically should be install in the same device,For this i have intialize intent filter in androidmanifestfile.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".OneAppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name="com.twoproject.two.TwoAppActivity"
              android:label="twoapp">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I can install the two application into my device but when i launch the Oneproject then i am not able to lanuch the Twoproject.how can i install two applications(apks)with single installation and launch?

any body plzzz help me......

Comment: In the interests of clarity, what does "when i launch the Twoproject then i am not able to lanuch the Twoproject" mean?

Comment: sry print mistak.plz check with update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse right click on OneProject>Properties>java Build Path> In right window click Project>Add>TwoProject>OK>OK

Thats it!!! When u install OneProject TwoProject will get installed. Console will show found dependency.

cheers!!

Remove this from Oneproject:

```
      <activity android:name="com.twoproject.two.TwoAppActivity" 
     android:label="twoapp"> 
         <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
       </intent-filter> 
      </activity>
```

Add this tags to the intent filter of OneProject:

```
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Both the applications get installed, I guarantee!!!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activity tag:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

now you manifest code will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".OneAppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name="com.twoproject.two.TwoAppActivity"
              android:label="twoapp">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now it will create two launcher icon on your device.That's what you are asking?

Comment: hey I have done same thing.I can able two create two launch icons but when i launch the twoapp icon i am getting ClassNotFound Exception.asTwoAppActivity class.How can i resolve that?

Comment: please check have you defined the activity properly, it's path is accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, as the Android concept of an 'application' (as in the `<application>` element in the XML file) is pretty much tied to a single .apk file.

However, you can achieve the same effect but simply copying all the activities from TwoProject into OneProject. A single application can have multiple launcher icons so from the user's perspective it'll still look like two runnable things on the launcher. Plus, this way you get to share code and resources. Does that suffice?